# How many bytes can a keypress return? And should a metafied key return more?

Tags: keyboard, unicode, input, stty

I've been tooling around w/ this [input reader](http://gdriv.es/mikeserv/scripts/printkey.sh.html) lately. Currently it only prints a report to stdout for each key pressed while it runs, but I would like to graduate it to a higher purpose sooner than later, as it seems to be coming along ok. So far it has a few things going for it:

1. All its output is the result of a few concurrent processes in a single pipeline.
2. It interprets and reports on each keypress as soon as it is made.
3. It *(to the best of my knowledge)* reports on as many bytes per keypress as are sent for each keypress.

For example, if I run it and press the following keys/key-combinations in order ...

1. <kbd>a</kbd>
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
3. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>
4. <kbd>UP</kbd>
5. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>

...it prints the following to the terminal screen, a line per keypress and as soon as each keypress is made:

```
 a:97
 \n:10
 \240:160
 \e:27 [:91 A:65
 \e:27 [:91 1:49 ;:59 5:53 A:65
```

...where each byte in each keypress is printed like...

```
<space>(printable char|\C-escape|\octal-escape):[decimal byte value]
```

... as I considered appropriate.

Some of it confuses me though:

1. Though I think I've tried all of the keys, and though I've definitely set `stty` to send 8-bit chars *(w/ `cs8`)*, the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> combo seems to be the only one reporting any constituent byte higher than ASCII decimal 127.

   - This is especially confusing as I assume it has something to do with the <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier *meta*fying *(a concept which I admittedly understand very little about)* the key sequence, but in seemingly every other case <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>*anykey*</kbd> just prefixes an <kbd>ESC</kbd> to the sequence, or otherwise subtly modifies an already escaped sequence.
   - Should <kbd>ALT</kbd> *not* be shifting the sent sequence into the higher 128 - 255 range?
   - *(in a comment below derobert indicates the reader successfully interpreted and reported on multi-byte UTF-8 `compose` sequence)* 
     *Note: `locale` reports all `LC_*` categories are set to `en_US.UTF-8`*
2. Also concerning is that while I seem to get all of the bytes for each keypress, in its current form my script will delimit keypresses at <strike>8</strike> now 32 bytes maximum.

   - I previously thought *8 bytes* sufficient, but I grow doubtful now when I consider whether multibyte chars in other locales might be combined with some of the longer escape sequences I'm seeing. And so I have extended the buffer - but with less certainty than 8 bytes initially provided me.
   - Is there an upper-limit to how many bytes might be sent in a single keypress?

Comment: `compose - - .` got me  `\342:226 \200:128 \223:147`. You can of course map – to one keypress, instead of the many I used...

Comment: @derobert - hmm... is that a good thing? Oh, right - so that's *supposed* to send the one sequence, right? Or...? Sorry, man, I asked this question because I'm really lacking in understanding in the not-painted-on-my-keyboard department. By the way, if you just ran it straight out of copy-paste, you might want to make sure those `^key` portions of the script are actually some non-printable char rather than just the literal `^char` printables.

Comment: Yeah, I did a copy and paste, from a browser. You might want to post a link where someone can just `curl` it w/o it being corrupted... I'm not sure what it should print. UTF8 characters are multiple octets. Certainly a single keypress can produce a UTF8 character. (But with macros, a single keypress could also produce many plain ASCII characters.)

Comment: @derobert - right. So did you get three lines or just three bytes? By the way, though, there shouldn't have been any issue with those - those would just be octal escapes which are used when those non-printables are *not* matched.

Comment: It was all on one line. But I probably corrupted your script when copying & pasting.

Comment: @derobert - on the off chance you care, I have factored out much of the logic that before resulted in 3 nested loops in the `loop()` function to another *(much smaller)* function entirely and significantly reduced the complexity in `loop()`. I also quadrupled the block factor to make the upper limit per sequence 32 bytes now for a performance cost of *(apparently)* nil. I can't seem to get the `sh` process to eat more than 1% CPU at any one time. I also got explicit about glob/IFS and so cleared out a lot of otherwise unnecessary shell quotes. It's an overall improvement, I think.

Comment: @derobert - I still can't figure out `compose` though. I don't suppose you could point me to a reference or two *(something which describes mechanism as well as purpose, hopefully)*...?

Comment: Well, compose is just a way of typing extra characters, e.g., compose+c+, = ç. I have it instead of a caps lock key. Not sure how exactly X11  implements it, though.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually several questions.  Some deal with terminal-specific behavior and some deal with compose.

First, there is a question regarding the expected behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd> used as a modifier.  Some people equate the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (which is labeled on many keyboards) with <kbd>Meta</kbd> (which is rarely labeled as such on terminal keyboards).  And some go further, equating it with the escape character. Call that a *conventional* use.  In xterm, at least, the association is configurable (since [patch #122 in 1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_122), it has the `metaSendsEscape` resource, and [patch #225 in 2007](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_225) added `altIsNotMeta` and `altSendsEscape` resources).  Other terminal emulators (and their users, perhaps) are not so flexible.  So there's a *convention* which equates escape and meta.  Conventions are not standards.

The documented behavior of the meta key is in the [terminfo(5) manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous):

> If the terminal has a *"meta key"* which  acts  as  a  shift
>   key,  setting  the  8th  bit of any character transmitted,
>   this fact can be indicated with **`km`**.   Otherwise,  software
>   will assume that the 8th bit is parity and it will usually
>   be cleared.  If strings exist to turn this "meta mode"  on
>   and off, they can be given as **`smm`** and **`rmm`**.

There's no standard behavior for the case where meta mode is off (just convention).

Depending on the `eightBitInput` resource in xterm, it may construct codes higher than 128 using the meta key.  For instance, in [patch #183 in 2003](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_183), this change was made to avoid making the meta mode produce illegal UTF-8:

> - modify handling of eightBitInput resource in UTF-8 mode to translate the value into UTF-8. Otherwise an illegal UTF-8 code is sent to the application (report by Bram Moolenaar).

Generally speaking, however, most of the escape sequences that you might use with terminals and the *conventional* escape sequences that their keyboards return use 7-bit ASCII.  VT100s are no exception to this; that was the point of this change from [patch #177 in 2002](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_171):

> - modify parser tables to improve detection of malformed control sequences, making xterm behave more like a real DEC terminal (patch by Paul Williams).

That is, the parser tables are *mostly* organized to ignore the eighth bit of the input characters.  Other terminals may ignore that aspect, but still copy the escape sequences used for xterm's keyboard.  The result is that you *mostly* see 7-bit ASCII.

I'm using xterm as an example since most of the behavior you're likely to see started with xterm (and most of the *remainder* came from rxvt).  With xterm, you could have several cases where you get fairly long escape sequences from a key, e.g.,

- using the `modifyOtherKeys` mode, which assigns an escape sequence to (most of) the keys on the keyboard,
- using the `translations` resource, which let you send "any" sequence of characters, and
- using the `DECUDK` feature, which sends an application-defined string (as a sequence of hexadecimal digits).

Other terminals (such as OSX Terminal.app and iTerm2) also can send user-configurable strings.  From that standpoint, there's no well-defined limit on the number of bytes sent by a key.

On the other hand, compose is more well-defined: its result is a character (or could that be multiple characters?) in a given encoding.  Assume just a single character.  The maximum *standard* length of a UTF-8 encoded character is 4 bytes.  While you *could* see a user-configured key sending this data, mostly (because of compatibility and conventions) you won't see the two (escape sequences and encoded-characters) mixed together.

Further reading:

- [Alt-keys do not work in bash](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [What is the maximum number of bytes for a UTF-8 encoded character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533258/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-bytes-for-a-utf-8-encoded-character)